# Limit of url params from javascript to objective-c

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

Is there any limit on how many url params i can pass from the UIWebView to Objective-C? If I change the url for example to 
`"JSBridge://SendParamsToNative?params=how_many_params_i_can_send?` 
is there a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no limit on the number of parameters, but there may be a max character limit. The usual (though not definite) good-practice, will work with everything max URL length is around 2000 characters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)).